# Opencv installing problems: Permission error. Errno 13

Tags: python, opencv, permissions

After installing Nython and Numpy as well as other things I finally came to the thing I wanted to install the most, Opencv. since I needed to install Numpy first it took me hours to figure things out..

Anyway I get this error and I looked some things up. There is talk of this sudo thing, but I have no idea how to use it or what it even is.

Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: Try this: `pip install --upgrade pip` and then `pip install wheel`. Then do `pip install opencv-python`.

Comment: Thank you that worked, but now there is another problem.
http://prntscr.com/ghwplp

Comment: That is inside the folder: http://prntscr.com/ghwrq7

Comment: Which Windows version are you running?

Comment: I have windows 8.1 http://prntscr.com/ghwwes

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python See the "Q: Import fails on Windows... " part.

Comment: I removed everything that had to do with opencv in the Python36 file. I then reinstalled opencv with pip install opencv-python.

What stood out to me after the reinstallation was this: http://prntscr.com/ghx93o

Comment: So whats the problem if everything installed correctly?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ghxjcf I get this error, on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python it says that I need Visual C++ redistributable 2015, I already do. Although the version is slightly different. In both the x64 and x86 the number of the version is slightly higher which I assume the version I have is newer. http://prntscr.com/ghxlnk
As for  Universal C Runtime that's already on my computer.

Comment: Also is it normal that there is no cv2.pyd file anywhere. There is a cv2 folder and the contents of it are:  http://prntscr.com/ghxnsq

Comment: I think I figured it out, I just removed the _init_.py file from the cv2 folder. Now everything seems fine.. Please take a look http://prntscr.com/ghxuox

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
python3 -m pip install --user wheel    
python3 -m pip install --user opencv-python
```

this solved my problem